# Block based storage

Tags: linux, filesystems, io, b-tree

I would like to store a couple of entries to a file (optimized for reading) and a good data structure for that seems to be a B+ tree. It offers a O(log(n)/log(b)) access time where b is  the number of entries in one block.

There are many papers etc. describing B+ trees, but I still have some troubles understaning block based storage systems in general. Maybe someone can point me to the right direction or answer a couple of questions:

1. Do (all common) file systems create new files at the beginning of a new block? So, can I be sure that seek(0) will set the read/write head to a multiply of the device's block size?
2. Is it right that I only should use calls like `pread(fd, buf, n * BLOCK_SIZE, p * BLOCK_SIZE)` (with n, p being integers) to ensure that I always read full blocks?
3. Is it better to read() BLOCK_SIZE bytes into an array or mmap() those instead? Or is there only a difference if I mmap many blocks and access only a few? What is better?
4. Should I try to avoid keys spawning multiple blocks by adding padding bytes at the end of each block? Should I do the same for the leaf nodes by adding padding bytes between the data too?

Many thanks, 
Christoph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In general, file systems create new files at the beginning of a new block because that is how the underlying device works. Hard disks are block devices and thus cannot handle anything less than a "block" or "sector". Additionally, operating systems treat memory and memory mappings in terms of pages, which are usually even larger (sectors are often 512 or 1024 bytes, pages usually 4096 bytes).
   One exception to this rule that comes to mind would be ReiserFS, which puts small files directly into the filesystem structure (which, if I remember right, is incidentially a B+ tree!). For very small files this can actually a viable optimization since the data is already in RAM without another seek, but it can equally be an anti-optimization, depending on the situation.
2. It does not really matter, because the operating system will read data in units of full pages (normally 4kB) into the page cache anyway. Reading one byte will transfer 4kB and return a byte, reading another byte will serve you from the page cache (if it's the same page or one that was within the readahead range).
3. `read` is implemented by copying data from the page cache whereas `mmap` simply remaps the pages into your address space (possibly marking them copy-on-write, depending on your protection flags). Therefore, `mmap` will always be at least as fast and usually faster. `mmap` is more comfortable too, but has the disadvantage that it may block at unexpected times when it needs to fetch more pages that are not in RAM (though, that is generally true for any application or data that is not locked into memory). `read`on the other hand blocks when you tell it, not otherwise.
   The same is true under Windows with the exception that memory mapped files under pre-Vista Windows don't scale well under high concurrency, as the cache manager serializes everything.
4. Generally one tries to keep data compact, because less data means fewer pages, and fewer pages means higher likelihood they're in the page cache and fit within the readahead range. Therefore I would not add padding, unless it is necessary for other reasons (alignment).

Answer (score 3):

1. Filesystems which support delayed allocation don't create new files *anywhere* on disc. Lots of newer filesystems support packing very small files into their own pages or sharing them with metadata (For example, reiser puts very tiny files into the inode?). But for larger files, mostly, yes.
2. You can do this, but the OS page cache will always read an entire block in, and just copy the bits you requested into your app's memory.
3. It depends on whether you're using direct IO or non-direct IO.

If you're using direct IO, which bypasses the OS's cache, you don't use mmap. Most databases do not use mmap and use direct IO.

Direct IO means that the pages don't go through the OS's page cache, they don't get cached at all by the OS and don't push other blocks out of the OS cache. It also means that all reads and writes need to be done on block boundaries. Block boundaries can sometimes be determined by a statfs call on the filesystem.

Most databases seem to take the view that they should manage their own page cache themselves, and use the OS only for physical reads/writes. Therefore they typically use direct and synchronous IO.

Linus Torvalds famously disagrees with this approach. I think the vendors really do it to achieve better consistency of behaviour across different OSs.

Comment: Aye. Though the cynical thing about this (Mr. Torvalds disagrees...) is that database vendors have little choice to do otherwise, unless they want to spawn a thread only for disk IO, because `madvise`/`msync` is deliberately broken under Linux, the manpages lie to you, and KAIO reverts to synchronous operation if O_DIRECT isn't given.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out Direct IO (and how to determine the block size). In my opinion Direct IO might be great for DBMS because it gives you more control and is faster when done properly, although you loose a lot of comfort (buffering, read ahead, ...).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Doing otherwise would cause unnecessary complications in FS design.
2. And the options (as an alternative to "only") are ...?
3. In Windows memory-mapped files work faster than file API (ReadFile). I guess on Linux it's the same, but you can conduct your own measurements